# Django how to link to some part of a page

Tags: django, django-templates

I want a link in my webpage header bar that points to a certain part of a page (for example, the lower half). It's easily done with pure HTML but I wonder how to do it in django.

HTML version:

```
In base.html: 
<a href="/entrance.html#intro">Introduction</a>

In entrance.html:
<a name="intro"></a>
```

How can I do the same thing in django? Any better solutions than just writing one more view function?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Django. Just write your HTML template the way you already suggested.

Comment: The part after the `#` will never be seen by the server side. Its a purely client side thing to address sections within a document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in doing it with Django when compared to just normal HTML. Just continue doing it the HTML way.

Comment: Yeah I realized...Silly me

Comment: @OrlanoL We've all been there

Answer (score 0):

There's also another way to tag html elements by id AND use the url template tag from django:

https://engineertodeveloper.com/a-better-way-to-route-back-to-a-section-ids-in-django/

(Credits for Brian, who wrote the solution at the link above)

this can be very useful if you, for some reason, need to use the url method for creating your links.