# How to render template in Django and redirect to a certain fragment of the template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

A Django newbie question.

Let's say I have a template that contains three paragraphs and I render it in views.py. Is there a way to redirect to a certain paragraph of the template using render? and if not what are my options?

Comment: Template can not resolve this question,but  you can use html anchor to a certain paragraph.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37236314/django-how-to-link-to-some-part-of-a-page